# Reveal div when link is clicked

Tags: mootools, mootools-more

Using mootools.js 1.3.2 and mootools-more.js

As far as I can tell this is supposed to reveal the div and also hide the content and linkTab divs at the same time.

```
$('blogLink').addEvent('click', function(){
 $('homeLink').removeClass('active'); 
 $('linkTab').removeClass('active'); 
 $('blogLink').addClass('active');  
 content.slideOut();
 linkTab.slideOut();
 blogLink.slideIn();
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<a href="#" id="blogLink">Blog</a>
<div id="blogContent">
content here
</div>
```

It all works properly and that's OK but in addition to this, I also want to be able to give people a URL like http://mysite.com/#blogLink and have that blogContent div opened. When I do that now, it takes me to the top of the page and the blogContent div is hidden.

How do I do achieve that? I did try adding the mootools-smoothscroll.js and using the method outlined here http://davidwalsh.name/smooth-scroll-mootools but that just broke the entire page - would not load properly.

I have zero experience with mootools and weak on Javascript so please excuse me if I take a while to 'get' what you're trying to explain.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are you particularly attached to MooTools? If you're a JavaScript newbie, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is probably easier to use and definitely has a larger support community. But I'll post a solution that should work in MooTools for now:

If I understand you correctly, what you want to achieve is the following:

- The anonymous function you posted will run when "Blog" is clicked
- The function will also run if someone visits the page with `#blogLink` in the URL.

That's not too difficult to achieve:

```
// Once the DOM has loaded - so that our elements are definitely available
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    // Check for #blogLink hashtag, and reveal blog
    if(window.location.hash == 'blogLink') { revealBlog(); }

    // Make sure blog is revealed when link is clicked
    $('blogLink').addEvent('click', revealBlog);
});

function revealBlog() {
    $('homeLink').removeClass('active'); 
    $('linkTab').removeClass('active'); 
    $('blogLink').addClass('active');  
    content.slideOut();
    linkTab.slideOut();
    blogLink.slideIn();
}
```

You could also change your link mark-up to:

```
<a href="#blogLink" id="blogLink">Blog</a>
```

To make sure they're always on the correct link when the blog is revealed.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense to me. Unfortunately, something else must be interfering. I moved the reveal into a function and implemented all as you suggested. Clicks on same page works perfectly but when I enter  http://site.com/#blogLink directly into browser address bar or click on a link from another page I still get the top of the page and the blogContent DIV is hidden.

I'm definitely not married to mootools but right now I simply want to fix something that was not created by me. Would love to switch later though.

Comment: I see this also and wonder if it is interfering.
`var blogLink = new Fx.Slide('blogContent', {
           onComplete: function(){
                $('blogContent').setStyle('height', '20000px');
           }
       });`

Comment: It's difficult for me to work out what's wrong with it without seeing the whole page in action, or at least all the pertinent code. It's possible that it's not working when you visit the URL because MooTools has to prepare some stuff before that function can successfully run, so 'domready' is too early. You could try changing the above code to: `if(window.location.hash == 'blogLink') {setTimeout(revealBlog,5000);}`. This will run it 5 seconds after the page loads, which should give MooTools time to prepare anything that's needed. If that works you know that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I know it is tough to troubleshoot without seeing things. I truly appreciate all your help and will give that a whirl.